# How Can You Save Multiple Files At Once with WinJS?

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, winjs, windows-10-universal

I'm making a WinJS app for Windows Store for Windows 8 and 10. I'm producing an app for my company, and at the end of a user process they are expected to click an Export button which saves about 10 files to a folder of their choosing.

Now, I know how to use a `Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker()` to save individual files, but I don't want to give the user the burden of accepting the save of each of the 10 files -- I just want the user to accept the folder they're going into, and then it saves them all in one swoop.

Is that possible in WinJS?

Comment: Use `.FolderPicker()`, then add the filenames to the path.

Comment: @ChrisG would you mind sending some example code in a pastebin about how I can use the FolderPicker() api, and get an array of filenames and filecontents writing into that folder? I would appreciate it so much!

Comment: I won't, sorry. I found the FolderPicker call via google's autocomplete, I didn't even open the page. You get paid to do this, and the work is cut out. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I don't want to give the user the burden of accepting the save of each of the 10 files -- I just want the user to accept the folder they're going into, and then it saves them all in one swoop.

You can use [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1) to get the target folder and use [StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227250.aspx) to generate 10 files and copy the contents you want to the file:

```
var pickers = Windows.Storage.Pickers;
var DataWriter = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter;
...
document.getElementById("btnSave").onclick = function (evt)
{
       var content = "Test Content";
       var picker = new pickers.FolderPicker();
       picker.suggestedStartLocation = pickers.PickerLocationId.computerFolder;
       picker.fileTypeFilter.append(".txt");
       picker.pickSingleFolderAsync().then(function (folder) {
       if (folder != null)
       {
           for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
               folder.createFileAsync("testFile" +i+ ".txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
                    .then(function (file) {
                        file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite)
                            .then(function (randomAccessStream) {
                                var dataWriter = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.getOutputStreamAt(0));
                                dataWriter.writeString(content);
                                        dataWriter.storeAsync().done(function () {
                                            randomAccessStream.close();
                                            dataWriter.close();
                                });
                            }, errorHandler);
                    }, errorHandler);
                }
            }
        }, errorHandler)
}

function errorHandler(error){}
```